# android:layout_above error when refrencing RelativeLayout ID

Tags: android-layout

I am getting a strange problem using what seems like a simple layout. This is the line that keeps erring out.

```
android:layout_above="@id/layoutButtonOrganizer"
```

I does exist in the in the R.java file

```
 **public static final int layoutButtonOrganizer=0x7f090003;**
```

The Error I am getting is

```
**error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/layoutButtonOrganizer').**
```

It compiles fine unless I try to use the id to align a button above it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.MasinoMike.mmasinolab4_1.MainActivity" >

<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonShowAnswer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ***android:layout_above="@id/layoutButtonOrganizer"***
        android:text="@string/buttonTextShowAnswer" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutButtonOrganizer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:text="@string/buttonTextNext" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPrevious"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/buttonTextPrevious" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

After working on this for a few hours I figured out what was going on. Even though the LinearLayout is below the button that I am referencing it from (My Button is above the layout in the xml file) I have to load the reference ID the first time it is used with the @+

```
android:layout_above="@+id/layoutButtonOrganizer"
```

The solution is to always make sure to have @+ the first time that you use a resource reference in your xml file. It feels sort counter intuitive to load the reference before creating the View object the id belongs to, but whatever makes the compiler happy.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonShowAnswer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        **android:layout_above="@+id/layoutButtonOrganizer"**
        android:text="@string/buttonTextShowAnswer" />

    <LinearLayout


        **android:id="@id/layoutButtonOrganizer"**
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
```